# Google maps marker show only icon

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to display markers on google maps (android)

I used this code (like in the example in android developer):

The location, name and descripion are valid (I checked them via debug mode)

It shows me the icon on the desired location, however without the marker or the description and snippets. The following line

```
mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location)
    .title(poi.getName()).snippet(poi.getDescription())
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(image_item));
```

shows me only the icon without the title or snippest.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow the examples from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)? Also, the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code) bundled with the Google Play services SDK?

**Edit**: You can show an info window programmatically by calling `showInfoWindow()` on the target marker:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(location)
                      .title(poi.getName())
                      .snippet(poi.getDescription())
                      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(image_item));
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

However, bear in mind that only one info window can be displayed at a time. If a user clicks on another marker, the current window will be hidden and the new info window will be displayed.

Comment: hi, this is the same code that i wrote above. what is the problem with my code?

Comment: @AdirRahamim `new MarkerOptions()`

Comment: @AdirRahamim So when you tap the marker the title and snippet don't show up?

Comment: when i click on the icon it shows me the title and snippest, however i want that they will always be show up (not only when i click on the icon)

Comment: @AdirRahamim Your question wasn't clear. See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks alot...Also do you know why if the title or snippest are in other languages rather than english (like hebrew) it doesnt show the title and snippest ?  as i described here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233694/google-maps-marker-in-other-languages

Answer (score 1):

try this code.
This code is work on Google map with API V2
Add the inbuilt method of google.

public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

```
    // Getting the Latitude and Longitude of the touched location
    latLng = point;
    // Clears the previously touched position
    myMap.clear();
    // Animating to the touched position
    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    // Creating a marker
    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    // Setting the position for the marker
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    // Adding Marker on the touched location with address

    new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latLng);
    tmpLatLng = latLng;
    drawCircle(point);
    btLocInfo.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: thanks, what is the "ReverseGeocodingTask" class? and the btLocInfo var?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a rare problem the only way to fix it is to reinstall its the only way  was able to fix it .

Comment: hi, i didnt understand you..what do i need to reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

**show icon without the title or snippest.** use below code

```
LatLng newYork = new LatLng(40.7142, 74.0064);
Marker melbourne = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(newYork));
```

**Edited:**

### show marker with title & Snippest & icon

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                .title(string).snippet(string2).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(image_item));
```

Comment: hi, i want to display also the title and description, not only the icon..how can i show also the title?

Comment: when i click on the icon it shows me the title and snippest, however i want that they will always be show up (not only when i click on the icon)